# Liferay on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, liferay, liferay-6, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am configuring Liferay 6.2 GA1 on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk instance that has Tomcat 7 &Java 1.7 I followed steps mentioned in below Liferay forum

https://www.liferay.com/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/liferay-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-and-ec2

As per James all the Jar needs to be placed in Liferay-x.war & portal-ext.properties with liferay-home properties following this steps I was able to bring up the Liferay instance

Issue what I am facing here is while deploying portlet I am getting below ClassNotFoundException which seems class loader issue. All the necessary jars are added in ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/

I Could resolve this issue by following guide on Installing Liferay on Tomcat 7 by modifying tomcat configuration But I do not want to do this as AWS Scaling wont work in this case as new Instance will not take this tomcat configuration it will fail.

So I need to have a liferay.war configured & working independently without modifying tomcat configs. As per James in above forum it mentions with proper JVM settings class loader issue can be handled.

1. Has any one came across this situation ? Kindly share you solution or approach on handling the AWS Scaling for above issue.
2. How the RDS has to be configured for multiple instance as current I have 2 instance both having same RDS pointed but it is restricting me to login in Liferay.
3. Also in above case how S3 can be configured so all instance are able to access documents simultaneously

### Error Log:

```
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/marketplace-portlet
19 Dec, 2013 8:37:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4715)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1617)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
19 Dec, 2013 8:37:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SerializableSessionAttributeListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SerializableSessionAttributeListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4715)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1617)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
19 Dec, 2013 8:37:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
19 Dec, 2013 8:37:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
19 Dec, 2013 8:37:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/marketplace-portlet] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Comment: What do you see when you run `$ jar tf marketplace-portlet.war` on EC2 instance?

Comment: I was wondering, if you deploy `Liferay-x.war`, how do you end up with `marketplace-portlet` web context without modifying Tomcat `context.xml`?

Comment: Andrey marketplace-portlet get auto deployed after liferay-x.war is deployed successfully. I think it is added as dependency some where in  liferay.war

Comment: You said you added library jars to `ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/`, the source for root context ClassLoader. Those libraries will not be available in other contexts. If you want to add libraries to be shared between contexts, you should add them to `<tomcat home>/common/lib`, you can read more about Tomcat classloaders in [class-loader-howto](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) guide.